# Date fields query results to js function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

In KeystoneJS pug view, I need to pass an array with a range of dates from 2 MongoDB date fields to daterangepicker `isInvalidDate`

The query in the controller is:

```
view.query('booked', Booking.model.find({}, 'startDate endDate'));
```

In the jade view `= booked` returns:

```
{ _id: 58f71314a20fc062ee02f4df, startDate: 2017-04-18T21:00:00.000Z,
endDate: 2017-04-19T21:00:00.000Z },{ _id: 58f8768c0741e2118b1efe43,
startDate: 2017-04-23T21:00:00.000Z, endDate: 2017-04-25T21:00:00.000Z },{...
```

In the jade view js block, this snippet:

```
var books =!{JSON.stringify(booked, ['startDate', 'endDate'])};
```

returns:

```
startDate: 2017-04-18T21:00:00.000Z
endDate: 2017-04-19T21:00:00.000Z

startDate: 2017-04-23T21:00:00.000Z
endDate: 2017-04-25T21:00:00.000Z
```

How do I format the `startDate` and `endDate` properties to get the result:

```
["04/18/2017", "04/19/2017", "04/23/2017", "04/25/2017"]
```

(no labels, just the date values, comma delimited)

Comment: Where is `booked` defined for passing it to js function in your code ?

Comment: `booked` is a key in the view query in the controller

Per documentation: View class also provide a query(key, query, options) method to queues a mongoose query for execution before the view is rendered.The results of the query are set in locals[key].Keys can be nested paths, containing objects will be created as required.The third argument then can be a method to call after the query is completed like function(err, results, callback), or a populatedRelated definition (string or array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`booked` is exposed as a Pug variable, not a JavaScript variable. To pass a Pug variable (from your database) to JavaScript, you'll have to embed the direct contents of the variable in your page and then retrieve it as a JSON.

```
"isInvalidDate": function (date) {
    var books = !{JSON.stringify(books)}; // Now an array of objects
    // Your other code
},
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/shbelsky/pen/LyNOzQ?editors=1001)

The rest of your code will need to change due to how the dates are formatted in your DB, but `books` will now be the array of objects you need it to be. If you want to compare dates of format `MM/DD/YYYY`, the `endDate` and `startDate` properties in `books` will need to be properly formatted for comparison (or `-1` will always be returned).